# sass won't compile, file unreadable or not found

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Sass encountered an error while converti
ng 'assets/css/all.sass':
                    File to import not found or unreadable: 1-tools/-tools-dir.
on line 1

That is the error i get every time i run Jekyll and i can't seem to fix it. I've tried everything that i found on Google and still can't seem to make it work.
Any idea what is wrong with the includes?

My files are like this:

```
_-tools-dir.sass
@import 'bourbon/bourbon'
@import 'fonts'
@import 'normalize'
@import 'vars'

_-sections-dir.sass
@import 'header'

all.sass

---
---

@import '1-tools/-tools-dir'
@import '2-base/-base-dir'
@import '3-sections/-sections-dir'
```

and in base-dir i have no includes yet so the file is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default Jekyll settings, all *sass/scss/coffee* imports are supposed to be in `_sass` folder.

Your `@import '1-tools/-tools-dir'` import rule is looking for `_sass/1-tools/-tools-dir.sass` file and not `_sass/1-tools/_-tools-dir.sass` (note the underscrore).

You can change the import to `@import '1-tools/_-tools-dir` or change the file name to `-tools-dir.sass`.

Same for other imports that will cause the same not found error.

Comment: @Tzede make sure you also move all the sass folders inside `_sass` as that's the default location Jekyll looks for sass files. Then try what David has mentioned again.

Comment: But can i change the default folder? I mean can i tell jekyll that i have a new default folder?

Answer (score 0):

you're probably doing the [YouTube tutorial from DevTips](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqGj3iMvMa4KQZUkRjfwMmTq_f1fbxerI) (which is a pretty good one imo).

**Add this to your `config.yml`:**

```
sass:
  sass_dir: assets/css
  style: :nested
```