# Jekyll can't process scss

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to follow the step by step tutorial [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/07-assets/)

Here is my structure :

```
_config.yml  _data/  _includes/  _layouts/  _sass/  404.html  about.md  assets/  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  index.html
```

and _sass :

```
ls _sass/
main.scss
```

and assets/css :

```
ls assets/css/
styles.scss
```

and when I `jekyll serve` I get :

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/styles.scss':
                    File to import not found or unreadable: main. on line 1
```

So somehow jekyll is not able to find the main.scss file but I don't understand why since apparently everything is set up as it should be. Any idea ?

Also here is my `style.scss`:

```
---
---  
@import "main";
```

and my `main.scss` :

```
.current {
  color: green;
}
```

If I change styles.scss to :

```
---
---
.current {
  color: green;
}
```

Then it works since it does not try to import main.scss. I tried with/without `_config.yml` for specifying the sass directory. This does not change anything.

Comment: Does this post help you resolve the error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045976/sass-wont-compile-file-unreadable-or-not-found?rq=1  Can you share your code to help further debugging?

Comment: No does not. I will edit